# Change Volumes when saving outputs?

Tags: qgis, mac, working-directory

Im sure there is a simple answer to this but its eluding me. When saving outputs/QGIS projects the file navigator interface opens up and I can go through my files until I find the place I want to save the work/project. However, my machine has two disks, a 256GB SSD and a 2TB HD. The QGIS installation is on the SSD but I save all of my work on my HD because of its larger capacity. However, I can't change volumes when I want to save my work. It will allow me to navigate the SSD but I can't see where I can change the volume Im saving the work to. I could save it in a temp folder and move it later, but its a bit of a pain. When I click on the volumes under 'favourites' or 'recently used', only the SSD is listed.

Is there a way to change the directory to the volume I want?

I have the latest QGIS (pisa) on a Mac OS